# Implement an interface that extends comparable

Tags: java

So I have an interface Foo is constructed like:

`public interface Foo<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

and I'm trying to implement Foo in my class bar like:

`public class Bar<T> implements Foo<T>`

but I get getting the error `type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2`

but when I try to implement Foo as:

```
public class Bar<T> implements Foo<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

I get `> expected` and `<identifier> expected`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off. Try moving the bounds to the declaration of `T` as in this:

```
public class Bar<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Foo<T> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh god that was it?! Wow, I literally just spend and hour trying to fix this.

Comment: ... because in this case `Bar` is _declaring_ `<T>` and simply passing it as a _parameter_ to `Foo`.  Just like when you declare a variable and pass it to a method, the type of the declaration must satisfy the bounds of the recipient in order for it to compile.